# Disable integrity check for local dependency in package-lock.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

How can I disable the integrity check for a local dependency in package-lock.json?

In my repository, I have a base library as well as two Angular apps with both use my base library as dependency.

Unfortunately, the integrity *sha512* of the base library is with every build different, and npm fails installing the dependencies.

This is what it outputs:

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting @me/base-library@file:../lib/me-base-library-1.0.0.tgz:
npm ERR! Verification failed while extracting @me/base-library@file:../lib/me-base-library-1.0.0.tgz:
npm ERR! Integrity check failed:
npm ERR!   Wanted: sha512-(...)
npm ERR!    Found: sha512-(...)
```

Excerpt from "package-lock.json":

```
"@me/base-library": {
  "version": "file:../lib/me-base-library-1.0.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-(...)" // <- different with every build
}
```

Is there any way to disable integrity checks for local dependencies?

Comment: Why is it different on each build?

Comment: Oh, because it is a locally built file, sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the issue by referencing to the directory of my library instead of the TGZ file. npm and yarn (both tested) do not generate integrity hashes for folders, only for files. In my `package.json` files of the Angular apps, I have just changed `"@me/base-library": "file:../lib/me-base-library-1.0.0.tgz"` into `"@me/base-library": "file:../lib"`.

Additionally, I had to add some properties to the `package.json` file of base library:

```
  "main": "lib/bundles/me-base-library.umd.js",
  "module": "lib/fesm2015/me-base-library.js",
  "es2015": "lib/fesm2015/me-base-library.js",
  "esm2015": "lib/esm2015/me-base-library.js",
  "fesm2015": "lib/fesm2015/me-base-library.js",
  "typings": "lib/me-base-library.d.ts"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure such a possibility exists – basically, it would be a switch to toggle security issues on.

To fix this issue without introducing security issues, you could re-install the package again, which should update the value of `integrity`:

```
npm install file:../lib/me-base-library-1.0.0.tgz
```

To automate this, you can create an npm script:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "update-base": "npm install file:../lib/me-base-library-1.0.0.tgz"
  }
}
```

```
npm run update-base
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea for a workaround. Unfortunately, the fixed version in the script command would make it difficult for us to automate the install on our build server. After first experiments with yarn, we figured out that yarn can handle local dependencies as we need without any workaround. So, we will migrate from npm to yarn.

Comment: Good to know! It would be great if you post your findings as an answer to the question

Comment: Just posted :) Finally, I could even make it work with npm.